# java generics wildcard compiling error (generic of generic)

Tags: java, generics

Hello I have a compiling problem with this peace of code. How can I perform a safe add to data variable?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foo
{
    private TreeSet<? extends Collection<String>> data;

    public Foo()
    {
        data = new TreeSet<ArrayList<String>>();  
        data.add("Goofy"); //this action generates a compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the compile error you are getting?  Did you google the error message?  What did you find?  Why didn't it help you?  You need to do all of this before posting here.  Unless there happens to be a user who is one vote away from reaching 10k rep or something.

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to add a `String` to a `TreeSet` of `ArrayLists` of `String`s.  You would need to add an `ArrayList`.  Probably

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Goofy");
data.add(list);
```

That is, assuming you're not using an overcomplicated design, which you very much probably are.

Comment: @pXL yes!  I've been waiting for a stupid Java question for like 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

data is a collection of ArrayList and you are trying to add a String

You need to add the String to an array list first

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Goofy");
data.add(list);
```

or change data to be a TreeSet of Strings

```
private TreeSet<String> data;
data = new TreeSet<String>(); 
data.add("Goofy");
```